# MySQL 5.5.56 Temporary table always empty when used in a trigger but works when manually running the query

Tags: mysql, triggers, temp-tables

Can someone help or clear things for me. I've got this SQL code that I need to run on a trigger that doesn't work. But works when manually running the code on an SQL client.

```
SET @sr_id = NEW.purchase_id; /* SET @sr_id = 123456 when run manually */
SET @ndi = (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM purchase_rewards a LEFT JOIN item b ON b.id = a.item_id WHERE a.unit_id IS NOT NULL AND COALESCE(b.is_privileged,0) = 0 AND a.purchase_id = @sr_id);
SET @res = @ndi - CEIL(@ndi/2);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS for_removal;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE for_removal
    SELECT ID FROM (
        SELECT a.id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `rank` FROM purchase_rewards a LEFT JOIN item b ON b.id = a.item_id
            WHERE a.purchase_id = @sr_id AND COALESCE(b.is_privileged,0) = 0
        ) ft CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE `rank` <= @res;
        
DELETE ta FROM purchase_rewards ta INNER JOIN for_removal tb ON ta.id = tb.id WHERE ta.purchase_id = @sr_id;
```

The code queries the purchased items that are not "privileged", putting a rank column on each and removing half of them. You only get rewarded for half of it, that's the point. The software was created by someone else with no source code so this is a piggy back system behind it.

I placed debug codes in between each to see if the connection changes or the results where empty but all is good except for the last part. Before the delete part I added a debug code:

```
SET @icount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM for_removal);
INSERT INTO debug_log SET `log` = @icount;
```

and the result is that the table is always empty. I also tried converting the code into a stored procedure but I'm getting the same problem. Only running the code manually where it works.

I'm currently settling on CURSOR and loop-deletes which works, but it is slower when there are hundreds of items.

Sample Data: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=884ed25db4df33672c2bede085d7d6db)

Thanks!

Comment: which mysql version are you using. the ise of user defined variables was greatly teduced in mysql 8

Comment: @nbk its mysql 5.56

Comment: thy, please make a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=469235823316f5e4708251462f062ffc with some sample data, so that we can reproduce your problem. temporary tables as session based. i don'zt think that is a problem, but for testing this should be recognized. You should think about upgradung your mysql database as mysql 5.5 is quite old,

Comment: There has never been a version 5.56 of MySQL. Can you please run `SELECT @@version;` in an SQL client and report what it says?

Comment: @BillKarwin my bad. it's 5.5.56 though I've tested this upto 5.7 and still get the same weird behavior. I can't upgrade the MySQL version as this old program won't run properly and we don't have the source code.

Comment: I bet `@rownum` is not getting set before the subquery runs. Try `SET @rownum = 0;` before you try to create the temp table. Then you can also remove the `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I give you sympathies, it's no fun to work on a system that has been neglected like that.

Comment: @BillKarwin OMG! adding `SET @rownum = 0;` is the answer! it worked! Got me confused because even without it, it works running a manual query but NOT on a trigger/procedure/event. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the answer is to set the `@rownum` variable before the query.

```
SET @rownum = 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...
```

The reason is that you can't depend on the order of table evaluation in the CROSS JOIN. If the subquery is evaluated before the initialization of @rownum, then @rownum will be NULL, and any attempt to increment it with @rownum := @rownum + 1 will also yield NULL. So `rank` will have NULL on every row, and no rows will satisfy the WHERE clause.

As for why this works in the MySQL client but not in the trigger, I have a theory:

The session variable `@rownum` will keep its value if you test your query multiple times. So if you set it to some non-NULL value once in a session, then test the ranking query in the same session subsequently, it will increment.

But if you run it as part of a trigger, it will likely be a brand new session each time, and the value of `@rownum` will be initially NULL.